# Why isn't (function(){}()); working, yet window.onload is?

Tags: javascript, html, iife

I was experimenting with javascript the other day, and wanted to see whether a certain function  would work. So I did my HTML:

```
<body>
    <p id="paragraph"></p>
</body>
```

(of course, in the actual document I have set my doctype and created html tags and so forth)

And then wrote my javascript (which was linked to in the head correctly):

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerText = "Hi there!";
}());
```

Now, I opened my html and was a bit confused as to why my `<p>` did not contain any text, so I thought maybe the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) wasn't running on page load, so I tried something else:

```
(function(){
    console.log("Hi there!");
}());
```

Opened it again, and saw that the javascript had run fine that time; the console had printed 'Hi There' just as normal. I was a bit confused now, so then I tried:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerText = "Hi there!";
}
```

And it all worked perfectly! The paragraph contained 'Hi there' just like it should have (well, I think so) the first time!

Can anyone account for this absurd behavior? Why isn't `(function(){/*stuff*/}());` working for the `.innerText`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(function(){
console.log("Hi there!");
})();` instead of `(function(){
    console.log("Hi there!");
}());`?
I just modified the last brackets.

Comment: Because of "*which was linked to in the head correctly*". In the `head` the DOM is no yet ready so the `getElementById` will fail since it cannot find that element yet..

Comment: Besides, really no need to wrap the whole statement in parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way browsers work in most cases, is they process the html file first (including executing any scripts in it, in order), **then** create DOM elements such as your paragraph.

So when your IIFE was executed, the paragraph didn't exist yet (surely this must have printed something to your console too).

console.log is a different thing - the console object exists before the html is even loaded, which is why that worked fine.

Also, you want a lower-case **d** in getElementById

Answer (score 1):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

[MDN - window onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload#Notes)

if you do something like this it will work:

```
// wait for the dom to be ready...
window.onload = function(){
    // update the element...
    (function(){
        document.getElementById("paragraph").innerText = "Hi there!";
    }());    
}
```